# How to assign loaded nodejs module to a variable in Bash?

Tags: bash, shell-script, command-line, node.js

I don’t understand anything in the Bash language yet. I decided to learn how to make an NPM module. I made it for use through a connection in files. But then I decided to make it possible to execute it through the console.

example:
I run the file `run.sh`

this code will be executed

```
node -e 'require ("./ node_modules/@topus009/perf/x.js")'
```

but this code won't

```
var = $ {node -e "require ('./ node_modules/@topus009/perf/x.js')"}
error - bad substitution
```

How it should work:

- inside the loaded module the function is exported.
- loading module.
- then doing some bash scripts.
- and then I call this module.

But I don’t know how to get the module for future use and launch.
How to pass the module to a variable. Stackoverflow did not help. And I reached the limit there.

```
#!/bin/bash

#...code for parsing bash variables from command line (WORKS)

nm="./node_modules/@topus009/perf"
benchmarkStart=${node -e "require('${nm}/benchmarkStart.js')"} #(NOT WORKING - error - bad substitution)
benchmarkEnd=${node -e "require('${nm}/benchmarkEnd.js')"} #(NOT WORKING)

start=${node -e "${benchmarkStart()}"}
#...loop the target nodejs script file (WORKS)
end=${node -e "${benchmarkEnd(start)}"}

#...another module loading & execution to show perf comparison in terminal and show line chart
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because you are using incorrect syntax. What are you doing is `${...}` which is a [bash parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) to do variable manipulation. For example:

```
foo="abc"
echo "${foo^^}"
# outputs ABC instead of abc
```

To make it work, change it to either backticks ` ... ` or `$(...)`

So, it'll be:

```bsh
benchmarkStart=`node -e "require('${nm}/benchmarkStart.js')"`
or
benchmarkStart=$(node -e "require('${nm}/benchmarkStart.js')")
```